# SMT Timestamp converter throwing NullPointerException

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

**Using :** confluent-5.1.0

**SINK Configuration :**

```sh
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8083/connectors \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "dbz-sink-connector-1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type.name": "dbauditt4",
    "topic.index.map": "our3.platform.business:plat_index",
    "topics.regex":"our3.platform.business",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "connection.url": "http://localhost:9200",
    "group.id":"plot",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
    "transforms": "timestamp_convertor",
    "transforms.timestamp_convertor.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value",
    "transforms.timestamp_convertor.target.type": "string",
    "transforms.timestamp_convertor.format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS",
    "transforms.timestamp_convertor.field":"data.ts_ms"
  }
}';
```

**Sample message in kafka topic is  :**

```js
{
  "data": {
    "before": null,
    "after": {
      "Id": 331458,
      "business_id": 532334,
      "sms_opted": 1
    },
    "source": {
      "version": "0.7.5",
      "name": "our3",
      "server_id": 810143323,
      "ts_sec": 1548661255,
      "gtid": null,
      "file": "mysql-bin-changelog.001786",
      "pos": 1719980,
      "row": 0,
      "snapshot": false,
      "thread": 11674162,
      "db": "platform",
      "table": "business"
    },
    "op": "c",
    "ts_ms": 1548661255851
  }
}
```

Connector is throwing null pointer exception.

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter.inferTimestampType(TimestampConverter.java:422) at

Can someone please help me out. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: In Kafka Connect you can't refer to nested structure field by `.`, you have to extract value using ex. `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten` Transformation. I think, that without schema, you might have problem with mapping values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box, none of the SMTs support nested field access, such as `data.ts` (which I think you meant `data.ts_ms` instead)

It appears that you are using Debezium, so you can do [CDC Event Flattening](https://debezium.io/docs/configuration/event-flattening/), or you could just configure Elasticsearch to do [dynamic mapping for time fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection)

Comment: Thanks you so much for letting me know that SMTs doesn't support nested field access. 
CDC event flattening will not work for me because it removes the "before" data of change event. 
I am new to elastic and i exactly don't know how to convert "data.source.ts_sec" from epoch to dateTimeFormat. Thanks for guiding to look at dynamic mapping.. trying to understand it.

Comment: @SahilGupta, If you use `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten` Transformation with `.` as delimiter, you will be able to refer to field like that `data.ts_ms`.

Comment: @wardziniak: I am getting nullPointer if i use 'Flatten' transformer for the data generated by debezium.